# Why can't I see who +1'ed my Blogger post?

Tags: google-plus, blogger

I run a blog on Blogger with the Google Plus sharing enabled. [According to Google](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/2448457?hl=en), I should be able to see who is recommending my posts on G+.

When I click the +X link in the admin panel, the older posts have this:

[image: plus one]

With the G+ profiles linked and the users' names and avatars visible.

However, my newer posts have the popup like this:

[image: plus two]

I get a popup telling me how many people have +1'ed my post but no idea who those people are. **Why can't I see who is +1-ing my posts?**

Addendum notes:

- Per that help page I linked earlier, clicking +1 cannot be done if one does *not* have a G+ profile.
- I'm using IE 10.0.5 all updates installed.
- I've connected my G+ to my blog.
- I double-checked in Chrome 27.0.1453.94 m and the same things happened.

Comment: I have the same issue. Was your blog grandfathered in from the time before Blogger was bought by Google?

Comment: @jerseyboy I....don't think so? My blog is only 4 years old or so.

Answer (score 1):

I know that Blogger announced this feature, but I don't think it's ever worked.    It may be something to do with the idea of privacy - should you really see details of people who you have no connection to besides the fact that they +1'd your post.